# Inflate and bind view at the same moment in android

Tags: android, kotlin, layout-inflater

I'm trying to inflate a view for each object in list and bind it with data at the same moment, and that is how i implement this:

```
data.forEach { rule ->
        layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.rule_view_holder,
            this.rulesContainer
        ).apply {
            setOnClickListener { content.flipVisibility() }
            title.text = rule.title
            contentText.text = rule.content.fromHtml()
            rule.images.map {
                createImageView(this.context, it)
            }.forEach {
                contentImages.addView(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

Views inflated and inserted into LinearLayout properly, but it seems that data is bound only for last item in list, here is what i mean: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u79gQ.png) 
There is list with 6 items in it, so view inflating is definitely right (because of horisontal lines, that inflated for each view necessarily).

Also there is rule_view_holder layout [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kajDH.png)

Can you please help me fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You could inflate item xml without parent (pass `null`) and then call `addView`:

```
data.forEach { rule ->
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rule_view_holder, null).apply {
        setOnClickListener { content.flipVisibility() }
        title.text = rule.title
        contentText.text = rule.content.fromHtml()
        rule.images.map {
            createImageView(this.context, it)
        }.forEach {
            contentImages.addView(it)
        }
    }
    this.rulesContainer.addView(view)
}
```